# Why does my code to save a list to a file not work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am making a bot for a friend's discord server and they asked me to make a quote system. I tried to make a saving command with this code:

```py
@bot.command()
async def quotesave(ctx):
    with open("quotesfile.txt", "w") as filehandle:
        filehandle.writelines("s%\n" % quotation for quotation in quotes)
```

However, this does not add anything to the "quotesfile.txt" file. Can someone help me?

Comment: Where did you define quotes?

Comment: Also I can't make work of that ancient format style, I had to use `"{}\n".format(quotation)`

Comment: quotes were defined by: `quotes = []
@bot.command()
async def quoteadd(ctx, quote: str = None):
    if quote is None:
        await ctx.send("You must have a quote")
    else:
        quotes.append(quote)
        addquote = "Added quote '" + quote +"'"
        await ctx.send(addquote)`

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use `print` for tasks like this. You're probably already familiar with how it works, and it allows you to print to the terminal for testing purposes

```
@bot.command()
async def quotesave(ctx):
    with open("quotesfile.txt", "w") as filehandle:
        for quote in quotes:
            print(quote, file=filehandle)
```

Comment: But from there, how would I get the quotes back from the file?